# Unblock fread() if unread_bytes == 0, without timing out stream connection

Tags: php, sockets, stream, timeout, fread

I'm trying to process a stream that sends me discrete packets of information but has an unknown duration of time between packets--say, on the order of 1-10 seconds. I want to download the stream with a PHP script, but also save whatever data I have so far to my local database every 5 seconds whether the stream sends me data or not. Some 5-second interval records will be empty; this behavior is expected and desired, if that's how the data arrives.

I have some code like:

```
$fp = fopen($stream_url, 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {

    // Download stream
    $stream_data .= fread($fp, 128);

    // Process $stream_data
    [...]

    // Check time and save data
    if ($time_since_last_insert == 5) {

        // Save to database
        [...]

        // Reset vars to be ready for new data in the next loop iteration
        $stream_data = '';

    }

}
```

According to the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) I've read, fread() waits until it has read the specified number of bytes before returning anything to $stream_data. But I need it to "let go" if there are currently no bytes to read (i.e., stream_get_meta_data() says 'unread_bytes' == 0), and allow the code below to check the time and make the DB inserts as needed.

TL;DR, I need two processes to be running simultaneously:

1. Catch the incoming stream and process the data
2. Keep an eye on the time and insert whatever data has arrived (if any) into the database on a regular basis

Is it possible to check how many bytes are left in the stream before starting fread() and continue with my while-loop if unread_bytes' == 0? Or is it possible to set some sort of time-out on fread() specifically, without breaking the whole stream connection? I'm open to the possibility that PHP isn't the right language to do what I'm doing, but it's what I know so I'd really like to use it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes formulating a question for others is the best way to set you on the right track to finding the right answer for yourself. I noticed that one of the elements in the `stream_get_meta_data()` array was "blocking" => "true," and since I had just finished asking about unblocking `fread()`, that got me searching for a way to set "blocking" to "false."

Use: `stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);`, after `fopen()` but before the loop

([docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php))